# How to check if a key is pressed in Renpy?

Tags: python, renpy

I am making a visual novel in which I need to check if a key, let's say "a" is pressed, and jump to a label when the key is pressed.

For more context, in my game, the character say 3 sentences, 1 is right and the others are wrong, I need to check if "a" which is the key to "denounce" the information said is pressed, if it is pressed on a wrong sentence, it jump to the "fail" label, if the key is pressed on the right sentence it jump to the "success" label.

Here's the code:

```
# Here the A key is used to say that the information is True 
# If it is true, we go to the success label
# if not, we go to the failure corresponding label
# which goes back to where we made a mistake

label Testimony:
    Policeman "information 1"
    # if A pressed: 
        jump fail_T1
    # Else:
        jump T2
label T2:

    Policeman "information 2" # True information
    # If A pressed: 
        jump success
    # Else:
        jump T3
label T3:

    Policeman "information 3"
    # if A pressed: 
        jump fail_T3
    # Else:
        jump Testimony`
```

I tried to ask on discord server, check the renpy doc, on YouTube, I asked chatgpt but I don't find how to make what I want, and I don't want clickable buttons, I want to check if a key is pressed.

Comment: Is the player meant to respond within a certain time frame? If not, could this be solved with a simple menu of two choices, e.g. "Objection!" and "Continue"?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I don't want to use button or menu, I would like to allow the player to play without a mouse or a touchpad, and only with a few key like WASD and E.

Comment: In that case you may be interested in this doc: https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/screens.html#key